# Unzip command is Archiving instead of Extracting

Tags: command-line, archive, unzip

I m trying to unzip "Data.zip" into the current directory using:

```
unzip Data.zip
```

But i get a prompt:

```
Archive: Data.zip
replace /home/jaggib/Data.zip? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:'
```

It looks to me that it is creating archive instead of uncompressing it.

I tried to specify a destination directory, but that gives the same result.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. Am not following the syntax correctly or is there an additional argument that i have to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file itself probably has a file (or a directory) in it called "Data.zip" and therefor prompts you on what to do.Do this:

```
unzip Data.zip -d tmp/
```

It will create directory tmp/ and extract the files in that directory. Since that directory does not have a Data.zip it will extract without a warning.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what was happening. I found that the zip command that i was using 'zip -r --filesync --quiet /home/jaggib/Data.zip Data.zip' was actually creating zip within zip.

Comment: can you suggest whats wrong with my zip command?

Comment: Hmm nothing wrong but you do do a weird thing. If you do it like that you have a data.zip on disc and make a zipped file named data.zip that has data.zip in it. Restoring is possible but you can use the -d option as shown to keep the zip and get the zip from the zip (this is getting weird ;) )

Comment: Yeah. I get the unzipping part. But i am wondering, how do i sync the files on my current directory zip to the zip in my home directory, using the zip command. So that i dont get 'Data.zip' getting wrapped under the new 'Data.zip' after the zip command.

Comment: I would use another name for the zip command. Use the name data2.zip to zip the files (including data.zip)(?)